# ASP.NET 4 FileUpload and OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, openfiledialog

I use the `FileUpload control` to upload files to remote hosting server in C# ASPNET.

I have restrict the `FileUpload control` to upload a file type.

For example, I wanted to upload text file (txt) only so I put a validator, which allows txt only.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator   
id="FileUpLoadValidator" runat="server"   
ErrorMessage="Upload Text file only."   
ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.txt)$"   
ControlToValidate="FileUpload1">  
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The typical `Open File Dialog` looks like figure below where you can see Windows Explorer like features to navigate through folders and select a file.

[image]

how to do when the browse button click event handler will show an open file dialog and users will be able to select only text files?

[image]

Comment: Funny - i'm no expert but checking msdn it seems that this is not possible, there is no field or something for the fileupload control.

Comment: Just add `accept=`

Comment: @VDWWD working! thanks... `<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadControl" runat="server" accept="txt/*" />`

Comment: Just remeber that you can still upload other types. So check the data in the backend for the correct file type also.